# Не могу восстановить базу данных на SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, резервное-копирование, восстановление

Databases->Restore database...->Device->Указываю местоположение бэкап-файла->Add

В общем все по инструкции, но кнопка ОК в окне так и не активируется.
Где я накосячил\мог накосячить?[image: Собственно само окно Восстановления]

Comment: Имя целевой базы в destination не указано. И бэкап, похоже, пустой

Comment: @PashaPash, другой ПК этот же бэкап пустым не считает и преспокойно все восстанавливает. +Destination же должен назначаться автоматически при указании адреса файла с бэкапом. Может, надо настроить какие-то права, только какие?

Comment: Другой сервер - это тот, на котором сняли бэкап? У него версия та же? Или новее? У вас на скрине 2008-й, он может просто не понимать бэкапы от новых версий.

Comment: Или может вы просто не к том серверу подключились? В заголовке вопроса у вас 2017, у него версия 14.0. А на экране видна 10.0.1600 - это точно SQL Server 2008